PHPWord and DOMPDF: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Dompdf\Dompdf" not found
I'm trying to convert docx to PDF on woocommerce hook woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta and I've tried to make .docx from template and it worked well, but now I have to convert the docx to pdf because client wants to prevent edits in the documents.
I'm using phpword from another website and uploaded it into /wp-content/themes/mytheme/word/vendor/phpoffice/phpword/ and I was getting error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PhpOffice\PhpWord\Exception\Exception' with message 'PDF rendering library or library path has not been defined.'
So I've tried to fix download DOMPDF library into /wp-content/tehems/mytheme/word/vendor/dompdf/dompdf and upgraded my function by this code snippet:
$rendererName = 'DomPDF';
$dompdfcesta = '/www/domains/example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/word/vendor/dompdf';
Settings::setPdfRenderer($rendererName, $dompdfcesta);

So my whole function looks like this:
use \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory;
use \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings;
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', function($order_id) {
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    global $wp, $wpdb, $woocommerce, $post; 
    require __DIR__ . '/word/vendor/autoload.php';
    
    $rendererName = 'DomPDF';
    $dompdfcesta = '/www/domains/example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/word/vendor/dompdf';
    Settings::setPdfRenderer($rendererName, $dompdfcesta);
    
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    
    $formatted_billing_address = $order->get_formatted_billing_address();
    $shipping_country = $order->get_shipping_state();
    $currency = $order->get_currency();
      
    $email               = $order->get_billing_email();  
    $phone               = $order->get_billing_phone();
      
    $shipping_address_1  = $order->get_billing_address_1(); 
    $shipping_address_2  = $order->get_billing_address_2();    
    $shipping_city       = $order->get_billing_city();
    $shipping_state      = $order->get_billing_state();
    $shipping_postcode   = $order->get_billing_postcode();
    $shipping_country    = $order->get_billing_country();
    $dateofpurchase = date('j. n. Y', strtotime( $order->get_date_created()));
    
    $result = $wpdb->get_row ( "SELECT order_item_name FROM  {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items WHERE order_id = $order_id AND order_item_type = 'line_item'" );
    $ordered_product = $result->order_item_name;
    $fullname = $order->get_billing_first_name() . ' '. $order->get_billing_last_name();
    $fullnamenospace = $order->get_billing_first_name().''.$order->get_billing_last_name();
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $filename = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/smlouvy/' . $fullnamenospace.'.docx';
    $pdfname = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/smlouvy/' . $fullnamenospace.'.pdf';
    $template_gold = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/smlouvy/Potvrzeni-o-uzavreni-smlouvy-gold.docx';
    $template_silver = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/smlouvy/Potvrzeni-o-uzavreni-smlouvy-silver.docx';
    $template_bronze = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/smlouvy/Potvrzeni-o-uzavreni-smlouvy-bronze.docx';
    $template_tiket3plus = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/smlouvy/Potvrzeni-o-uzavreni-smlouvy-tiket3plus.docx';
    $template_tiket10plus = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/smlouvy/Potvrzeni-o-uzavreni-smlouvy-tiket10plus.docx';
    //var_dump($filename);
    if($ordered_product == 'GOLD') {
        $templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor($template_gold);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('nameorcompany', $fullname);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('street', $shipping_address_1);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('city', $shipping_city);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('zip', $shipping_postcode);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('datepurchase', $dateofpurchase);
        $templateProcessor->saveAs($filename);
        $phpWord = IOFactory::load($filename);
        $pdfWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'PDF');
        $pdfWriter->save($pdfname);
    } elseif($ordered_product == 'SILVER') {
        $templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor($template_silver);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('nameorcompany', $fullname);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('street', $shipping_address_1);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('city', $shipping_city);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('zip', $shipping_postcode);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('datepurchase', $dateofpurchase);
        $templateProcessor->saveAs($filename);
        $phpWord = IOFactory::load($filename);
        $pdfWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'PDF');
        $pdfWriter->save($pdfname);
    } elseif($ordered_product == 'BRONZE') {
        $templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor($template_bronze);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('nameorcompany', $fullname);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('street', $shipping_address_1);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('city', $shipping_city);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('zip', $shipping_postcode);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('datepurchase', $dateofpurchase);
        $templateProcessor->saveAs($filename);
        $phpWord = IOFactory::load($filename);
        $pdfWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'PDF');
        $pdfWriter->save($pdfname);
    } elseif($ordered_product == '3+KURZ') {
        $templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor($template_tiket3plus);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('nameorcompany', $fullname);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('street', $shipping_address_1);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('city', $shipping_city);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('zip', $shipping_postcode);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('datepurchase', $dateofpurchase);
        $templateProcessor->saveAs($filename);
        $phpWord = IOFactory::load($filename);
        $pdfWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'PDF');
        $pdfWriter->save($pdfname);
    } elseif($ordered_product == '10+KURZ') {
        $templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor($template_tiket10plus);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('nameorcompany', $fullname);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('street', $shipping_address_1);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('city', $shipping_city);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('zip', $shipping_postcode);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('datepurchase', $dateofpurchase);
        $templateProcessor->saveAs($filename);
        $phpWord = IOFactory::load($filename);
        $pdfWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'PDF');
        $pdfWriter->save($pdfname);
    }
          
      //}

 
}, 999);

But this still not helps, but I think I'm one step forward. Now I getting this in my debug log:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Dompdf\Dompdf" not found in /www/domains/example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/word/vendor/phpoffice/phpword/src/PhpWord/Writer/PDF/DomPDF.php:52

Now I don't know how to continue to do it correctly, so I'm here and looking for any advices.

Maybe it's an autoloader issue? It's definitely out of scope for WordPress-specific problems though.

Looks to me like it can't find a class so there may be something about the path and where you've stored things.

Hi guys, the mistake was there I've used phpword (probably some old and maybe customized version from another website) so I've removed all and deployed fully new dompdf and phpword and it helped. PS: If there's anyone who needs to show "č", "ř" and other chars I recommend to use mpdf instead of Dompdf.
